# Woocommerce add amount to price if certain country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add e.g 5$ to the price if the country is switzerland (CH).

I've found this code snipped with ads an surcharge, but I want to add it directly to the prices.. is this possible?

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
  global $woocommerce;

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
global $woocommerce;

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

$county     = array('CH');
$amount     = 5;

if ( in_array( $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ){
    woocommerce_get_price += $amount;
    woocommerce_get_regular_price; += $amount;
    woocommerce_get_sale_price += $amount;
    woocommerce_order_amount_item_subtotal += $amount;
    };

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter all the prices on the site with the following filters [woocommerce_get_price](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_get_price/), [woocommerce_get_regular_price](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_get_regular_price/), [woocommerce_get_sale_price](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_get_sale_price/), and [woocommerce_order_amount_item_subtotal](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_hook/woocommerce_order_amount_item_subtotal/).

The ones you need depends on the plugins you use and how they retrieve prices (payment method gateways for example) but the first three should be enough.

The rest of your function will be determined by how you decide where the user is (ip address, a location picker, domain name, or shipping location for members etc.) I would assume you want to use the IP address so the user never sees the lower prices.

Comment: That sounds about right. I am bit of a noob here.. can you provide some code for me? :/

Comment: That won't work. A filter is called with `add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );` and each filter has different arguments and returned variables.

You should start by reading: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-beginners-guide-to-wordpress-actions-and-filters--wp-27373 Woocommerce is just a wordpress plugin.